# Stratified sampling / QMC simulation for compound Poisson rv

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, compound-distributions, latin-hypercube, quasi-monte-carlo

I have a rv $X$ of the form
$$ X=\sum_{i=1}^N Y_i, $$
where $N$ is a discrete rv (often, but not always, Poisson) and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_N$ are continuous random variables, iid and independent from $N$.

I want to compute some quantities with a MC method with a stratified sample. These quantities may depend both on $X$ and on the $X_i$, and I would like to sample $N$ an the $Y_i$ in a way that minimizes the simulation error.

If it is useful to understand the problem, simple examples are:
$$ \mathbf E\left[\sum_{i=1}^N \max(0,Y_i-a)\right]\quad\text{or}\quad\mathbf E\left[ \max(0,X-k)\right],$$
more complex ones are of the form
$$ \mathbf E\left[\min\left(m,\max\left(0,\sum_{i=1}^N f(Y_1,\ldots,Y_{i-1})\cdot\min(b,\max(0,Y_i-a))\right)-k\right)\right]\quad\text{for some linear $f$.}$$

**What I have already tried**

1. Sample $N$ in a stratified way, then sample the appropriate total number of $Y_i$ in a stratified way, shuffle them and attribute them to each simulated scenario. In this case the simulated distribution of $N$ and $Y$ is very close to the theoretical one, but the one for $X$ is still unstable.
2. Sample $N$ as before, then in separate steps sample, in a stratified way, $Y_1$ for all scenarios where $N\geq1$, then sample $Y_2$ for all scenarios with $N\geq2$, etc. This gives a better approximation for $X$, but a worse one for $Y$.
3. Sample $N$ as above, Set $\ell$ equal to the max value of $N$, sample $Y_1,\ldots,Y_\ell$ for all scenarios with a latin hypercube sampling method, and then discard the $Y_i$ that I don't need. This method is very slowand similar to 1. in the outcome.

**Question**

Is there a sampling method that would work for my case?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really answering your question, but I think you can perform the Latin hypercube sampling quickly, and it does decrease your sampling error for many target metrics.  Here is how I would perform the sampling in R:

````r
require(lhs)

set.seed(1980)

N <- 10000
k <- 40 # N and Y_i
X <- randomLHS(N, k)

Y <- X
Y[,1] <- qpois(X[,1], 4)
# check to make sure we don't need a poisson variable bigger than we have
stopifnot(all(Y[,1] < k - 1))

for (i in 2:k)
{
  Y[,i] <- qnorm(X[,i], 2, 1)
}

g <- apply(Y, 1, function(z) 
{
  if (z[1] == 0) return(0)
  return(sum(z[2:(z[1] + 1)]))
})
hist(g, breaks = 25)

# expected mean of g is mean of poisson * mean of iid RV = 4 * 2
mean(g)

################################################################################
# assess sampling error of LHS approach

sims <- 100
res <- numeric(sims)
for (j in 1:sims)
{
  X <- randomLHS(N, k)

  Y <- X
  Y[,1] <- qpois(X[,1], 4)
  # check to make sure we don't need a poisson variable bigger than we have
  stopifnot(all(Y[,1] < k - 1))

  for (i in 2:k)
  {
    Y[,i] <- qnorm(X[,i], 2, 1)
  }
  res[j] <- mean(apply(Y, 1, function(z) 
  {
    if (z[1] == 0) return(0)
    return(sum(z[2:(z[1] + 1)]))
  }))
}
mean(res)
sd(res)

################################################################################
# assess sampling error of SRS approach

res2 <- numeric(sims)
for (j in 1:sims)
{
  X <- rpois(N, 4)
  res2[j] <- mean(sapply(X, function(z) {
    if (z == 0) return(0) else return(sum(rnorm(z, 2, 1)))
  }))
}
mean(res2)
sd(res2)

sd(res2) / sd(res)

```
````